# webpack: can't build correct font paths

Tags: css, fonts, webpack, vue.js, urlloader

I have a vue.js project - I used the webpack template.

We have custom fonts. I referenced them in my scss as follows:

```
$font-path: '~@/assets/fonts/';
@font-face {
    font-family: 'someFont';
    src: url('./#{$font-path}someFont/someFont.eot') format('eot'),
    url('./#{$font-path}someFont/someFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./#{$font-path}someFont/someFont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./#{$font-path}someFont/someFont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The build works great - the fonts are placed in `dist/static/fonts`. The problem although is, that the upper scss has the wrong reference: 
`https://.../projectXY/static/css/static/fonts/someFont.woff2`,
which should be `https://.../projectXY/static/fonts/someFont.woff2`.

We didn't change any webpack config stuff, so it looks like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[ext]')
    }
}
```

What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: Your css files are located in `./assets/css` and your fonts in `./assets/fonts`?

Comment: @floriangosse `./src/style/` to  be precise

Comment: I updated my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the relative paths in your `url` statements.

```
// ...
url('./#{$font-path}someFont/someFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
// ...
```

I think you can remove the `./` at the beginning of the url part.

---

**Update 1**

Try to use a relative path in your style.

Assuming that your folder structure looks like the following:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── fonts
│       └── font1.woff2
└── src
    └── style
        └── main.scss
```

Reference your font in your stylesheet with `../../assets/font1.woff2`. Which means in your case to also adjust the variable `$font-path`.

Comment: `assets` is in `src` too, sorry. Does that make a difference except that I have to use another `../`?

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem is at `$font-path: '~@/assets/fonts/';
`. The `~@` doesn't look right for me. Do you use [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader)?

Comment: Yes I do. The strange thing for me is that the build works perfectly fine but the references don't.